# Something wrong with the colon in a for loop (runtime error/ syntax error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I am a coder in Leetcode, and it says I'm wrong with a colon on a for loop.
This is my code:

```
class Solution:
def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    strnums = []
    for i in strnums: strnums += str(i)
    for n1 in range(1, len(nums) + 1)：
        for n2 in range(1, len(nums)+1):
            if nums[n1] == nums[n2]
                pass
            elif n1 + n2 == target:
                print(nums[n2])
            else:
                pass
```

there is something wrong with line 5 and 6,

will anyone help me?

Comment: Both the for loops are on same indentation level, which is wrong.

Comment: The 7th line is missing a colon. Note “something wrong” is vague. Give us the full traceback

Comment: The fourth line is also missing a colon. And the second line isn't correctly indented.

Comment: The colon on the fifth line prints differently than the other colons in my phone browser. Check that it is actually an ASCII colon.

Answer (score 0):

**Line 4**

```
for i in strnums: strnums += str(i)
```

`strnums` is empty, this loop will not iterate.

**Line 7**

```
 if nums[n1] == nums[n2]
```

missing colon at the end of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple colons are missing and the indentation is also missing in multiple places. Python is sensitive to indentation. The body of the for-loop, function, class, etc must be indented from its declaration:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        strnums = []
        for i in strnums: 
            strnums += str(i)
            for n1 in range(1, len(nums) + 1):
                for n2 in range(1, len(nums)+1):
                if nums[n1] == nums[n2]:
                    pass
                elif n1 + n2 == target:
                    print(nums[n2])
                else:
                    pass
```